# Angular 4. Edge. toJSON() toLocaleTimeString() Incorrect values

Tags: angular, request, microsoft-edge

```
toJSON() {
    return {
        "guaranteedTime": this.guaranteedTime.toLocaleTimeString("en-US"),
    }
}
```

Request body:

[image]

Is anyone has an idea why it's happens?

Comment: Except that you run this in angular is this angular related problem?

Comment: I looked into this and toLocaleDateTimeString [works fine in Edge](https://jsfiddle.net/6cLj7z98/1/). It seems that the error happens somewhere in the way you serialize the code into JSON. Could you provide more code around how you construct your request and pass data in it?